# What are the allowed comment characters in stan?

Tags: stan

I've seen `//` being used in some examples, but are there other permitted comment characters.

What are comment characters in Stan? What are the full set of commenting rules?

Answer (score 3):

From the [Stan reference manual](http://mc-stan.org/manual.html):

> **23.1. Comments**
>
> Stan supports C++-style line-based and bracketed comments. Comments may be used anywhere whitespace is allowed in a Stan program.
>
> **Line-Based Comments:**
>   In line-based comments, any text on
>   a line following two forward slashes (`//`) or the pound sign (`#`) is
>   ignored (along with the slashes or pound sign).
>
> **Bracketed Comments:** For
>   bracketed comments, any text between a forward-slash and asterisk pair
>   (`/*`) and an asterisk and forward-slash pair (`*/`) is ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Now the pound sign (`#`) is deprecated in STAN, although it is still valid. You may get a warning as follows.

> Blockquote
>   Info (non-fatal): Comments beginning with # are deprecated.  Please use // in place of # for line comments.

So I think you may take double slash (`//`) as your first choice.